# How to handle a question in review that is not for Stackoverflow?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

I got [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13136397) in Triage. Since it does not fit to Stack Overflow, I do not know what to do, because it does not need editing nor is it unsalvageable.

I opened it in a new tab and flagged it to be closed because it is not a Stack Overflow question.

**But what should I do in the review process with such questions?**

Comment: If you're not sure, skip!

Comment: That is not very helpful because I know that I can skip a question when I am not sure. But that is why I ask it here how to handle such questions.

Comment: As long as you're aware of that, plenty of people think that the skip button should never be pressed. As far as I'm aware, you did the right action, it's not something that should belong in that review queue, let it be closed and migrated when the other flags are picked up

Comment: [This is a rather good review on what to do with Triage questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) `questions that belong on another site should usually just be closed, but if they're particularly good, you can flag/vote for migration using close`

So in affect, it should be Unsalvageable for wrong site

Answer (score 3):

The [Triage review guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/4751173) says that these questions are:

> #### Unsalvageable
>
> Does the question belong on some other site?

---

You can flag from within Triage: click <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> -> Should be closed ... -> Off-topic because ...

There are a couple of options which fit here:

#### 1. Standard reason

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

This is the easiest option.

#### 2. Suggest migration

Suggest migration to another site, though it is only available for the top 5 migration targets. Choose this option

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

and superuser.com in the next window. [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) would be another option for this question, but it is not in the top 5 migration targets so it can't be chosen

#### 3. Custom reason

If you would encounter a question about e.g. English language, you can choose

> Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

and specify a custom reason.